# Mismatched vertical and horizontal sensitivity

Tags: pc, mirage-arcane-warfare

Mirage: Arcane Warfare has an increased emphasis on ranged combat over the developer's previous game Chivalry: Medieval Warfare and  vertical (y-axis) sensitivity is far lower than horizontal (x-axis) sensitivity. How to even out mouse sensitivity?